# How to optimally query the only first data row after a certain date?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table `Clients` with columns like this:

```
ClientId    LastChanged
671154  2012-07-21 14:35:40.780
671154  2012-07-21 14:35:41.630
671155  2012-07-21 14:37:24.213
```

I also have table `ClientsHistory` with columns like this:

```
ClientId    Changed                 Name                                    StateCode
671154      2012-07-21 14:35:40.780 91C6672EB2D4496AB34D3C                  22654624
671154      2012-07-21 14:35:41.630 55E345FE6A144B0E92A6026D8B461CEA        22654624
671154      2013-03-13 12:56:33.943 D32841A8EBAB44999C966D2F597DC240        22654624
```

I want to query `Clients` And Only First Row in `ClientsHistory` after `LastChanged` date:

```
SELECT  (   SELECT  TOP 1
                    Name
            FROM    dbo.ClientsHistory
            WHERE   ClientId    = c.ClientId
            AND     Changed     > c.LastChanged
            ORDER   BY  [Changed]   ASC
        )   ,
        (   SELECT  TOP 1
                    StateCode
            FROM    dbo.СlientsHistory
            WHERE   ClientId    = c.ClientId
            AND     Changed     > c.LastChanged
            ORDER   BY  [Changed]   ASC
        )   ,
        c.ClientId,
        c.LastChanged
FROM    Clients c
```

How to rewrite this query to eliminate subquery for every field in `ClientsHistory` table?

Comment: So to clarify, with the data as shown you will get `Name D32841A8EBAB44999C966D2F597DC240        ` displayed *twice*, yes?

Comment: You would need to examine the execution plan to determine what it is actually doing - it may have optimised the query.

Comment: "after LastChanged date" means _before_?

Comment: I may incorrectly name filed LastChanged.   But I mean select all clients changes in ClientsHistory table happened after certain date (LastChanged )

Comment: Use APPLY, as @larsis answered. If you add an index on `(ClientId, Changed)` it would be likely most efficient as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CTE, the ranking function `ROW_NUMBER` and a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
WITH Hist AS
(
    SELECT c.ClientId, Changed, Name, StateCode, c.LastChanged,
           RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.ClientId
                                   ORDER BY Changed DESC)
    FROM dbo.Clients c INNER JOIN dbo.ClientsHistory ch
         ON c.ClientId = ch.ClientId
    WHERE c.LastChanged > ch.Changed
)
SELECT c.ClientId, c.LastChanged, h.Changed, Name, StateCode
FROM dbo.Clients c LEFT JOIN Hist h
   ON c.ClientId = h.ClientId
   AND c.LastChanged = h.LastChanged  -- necessary since ClientId is not unique in hist
   AND h.RN = 1
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/29c775/15/0)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

To eliminate the need for a separate subquery for each column you could make use of [APPLY](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156.aspx) like this:

```
SELECT ch.Name, 
        ch.StateCode, 
        c.ClientId,
        c.LastChanged
    FROM dbo.Clients c
    OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 * 
                 FROM  dbo.ClientsHistory
                 WHERE ClientId = c.ClientId 
                    AND Changed > c.LastChanged
                 ORDER BY Changed ASC) ch
```

Here, the subquery will be executed for each row in Clients.

Comment: It is likely to be the most efficient method if there is an index on `(ClientId, Changed)`.

Comment: I'll remove my reservations about efficiency, then :)

Answer (score 0):

This query must return the same result. Can you test that :

```
SELECT temp.Name,
       temp.StateCode,
       c.ClientId,
       c.LastChanged
FROM Clients c
INNER JOIN 
     (SELECT TOP 1 c2.ClientId 
             c2.Name, 
             c2.StateCode
      FROM Clients c2
      INNER JOIN dbo.ClientsHistory ch
          ON ch.ClientId = c2.ClientId 
          AND ch.Changed > c2.LastChanged
      ORDER   BY  [Changed]   ASC) temp 
  ON temp.ClientId = c.ClientId
```

Comment: Table ClientsHistory may contain  several rows with the same ClientId, but with different Name, StateCode and Changed values. Your subquery (SELECT TOP 1 ...)   select ONLY ONE ROW !